# Probability to select a point along the perimeter of a square

Tags: probability

The probability to select a point in some interval along the perimeter of a $\frac{1}{4}\times\frac{1}{4}$ square, which its lower left vertex is at the origin, is equal to the length of the interval. Let $X$ be the random variable that represents the $x$ coordinate of the selected point. I need to find the CDF of $X$, and then show that $X$ cannot be either discrete or continuous.

So I broke this into cases: $P(X\leq 0) = P(X<0) + P(X=0)$. The probability $P(X<0)$ is zero, since the square is at the $x>0,y>0$ quarter plane. $P(X=0)$ is all the left side of the square, and therefore $P(X=0) = \frac{1}{4}$.

If $0<t<\frac{1}{4}$, then 
$$
P(X\leq t) = P(X<t) + P(X=t)
$$
The left summand can have two possibilities, either at the upper side or the lower side, and therefore is equal to $2t$. The right one is just 0. From this 
$$
P(X\leq t) = 2t
$$
For $t = \frac{1}{4}$, we get
$$
P(X\leq \frac{1}{4}) = P(X<\frac{1}{4}) + P(X=\frac{1}{4})
$$
The left one is the limit of the former case, and therefore equals to $\frac{1}{2}$, while the right summand is $\frac{1}{4}$ - all the right side. From this
$$
P(X\leq \frac{1}{4}) = \frac{3}{4}
$$

For $X<t$, where $t > \frac{1}{4}$, the probability is $1$. To sum up
$$
F_X(t) = \begin{cases}
0 & t< 0 \\
\frac{1}{4} & t = 0 \\
2t & 0<t<\frac{1}{4} \\ 
\frac{3}{4} & t = \frac{1}{4} \\
1 & t > \frac{1}{4}
\end{cases}
$$

$F_X$ is not continuous, and therefore no $f_X$ exist that satisfy $F_X(t) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^tf_X(x)d x$

Is my CDF correct? How do I show $X$ cannot be discrete? Is just showing that all the points $0<t<\frac{1}{4}$ satisfy $P(X=t) = 0$ enough?

Comment: One thing: CDF is continuous from the right, so $F(t)=1$ for $t>\frac14$ goes accompanied with $F(\frac14)=1$. Unfortunaly I must go now.

Answer (score 1):

Your CDF is not correct.

- if $t<0$ then $F_X(t)=P(X\leq t)=0$
- if $0\leq t<\frac14$ then $F_X(t)=P(X\leq t)=P(X=0)+P(0<X\leq t)=\frac14+2t$
- if $t\geq\frac14$ then $F_X(t)=1$

Note that $P(X=0)=P(X=\frac14)=\frac14>0$ so the distribution is not continuous.

Note that $P(0<X<\frac14)>0$ while $P(X=t)=0$ for every $t\in(0,\frac14)$, so the distribution is not discrete.